# ILT of hyperbolic functions

Tags: residue-calculus, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-laplace

I want to calculate the ILT of this function with the residue theorem:
$$F(s) = \frac{\cosh{(\alpha \sqrt{s})} \operatorname{csch}(\beta \sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{s}(s-\theta)}.$$

The branch cut is along the negative real axis, but I didn't get the right result.
Would you like to help me with this issue?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as $\frac{\cosh(\alpha \sqrt s)\text{csch}(\beta \sqrt s)}{\sqrt{s}}$ is an even function of $\sqrt{s}$, there is no branch cut required.  There are, however, poles at $s=\theta$, $s=0$, and $s=-n^2\pi^2/\beta^2$ for all integers $|n|\ge 1$.

Therefore, the Residue Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}(t)&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\cosh(\alpha \sqrt s)\text{csch}(\beta \sqrt s)}{\sqrt{s}(s-\theta)}e^{st}\,ds\\\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\cosh(\alpha \sqrt \theta)\text{csch}(\beta \sqrt \theta)}{\sqrt{\theta}}\,\,e^{\theta t}}_{\text{Residue at }\theta}+\underbrace{\frac1{-\theta \beta}}_{\text{Residue at }0}\\\\
&+\sum_{|n|\ge1} \text{Res}\left(\frac{\cosh(\alpha \sqrt s)\text{csch}(\beta \sqrt s)}{\sqrt{s}(s-\theta)}e^{st},s=-n^2\pi^2/\beta^2\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Up to now, I understand why two integrations along the  branch cut above and below are zero. Does the sum of residues at $s=\theta, 0, -n^2 \pi^2/\beta^2$ equal the residue at $\inf$ ?

Comment: @jacques There is no annulus having an infinite external radius for which $F(s)$ is holomorphic.  So, no.

Comment: I don't know how to deal with the series.

Comment: @jacques The series solution is fine.  I don't believe that there is a closed form solution.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will finish the following calculation based on your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.